# Nexus eligibility for Canadian PR previously resident in the US?

Tags: canada, nexus, cbp

I am a Canadian PR and Indian citizen who was previously living in the US on a student visa and have been living in Canada as a PR for 20 months. As such, I've been resident for a total of ≥ 3 years in the US and Canada but for fewer than 3 years in Canada. Am I eligible to apply for Nexus?

Comment: Given that nexus enrollment in Canada has been frozen for the last couple of years and no sign of reopening, I don't think it matters.

Comment: @nikhil Nexus enrollment centres in Canada are closed, but Canadians remain eligible to enroll at a U.S. centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is admissible if you have only resided in Canada or the U.S. during the past three years from the date of your application, subject to [exceptions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112308/which-permanent-residents-are-exempted-from-the-3-year-residency-rule-in-nexus-a).

You do not have to have full three years in either country, but the residential stays have to be consecutive. You need to be prepared to provide evidence of your past residency (e.g. leases, I-94, work permit, study permit, I-20).

The exact wording of the [Canadian regulations](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/Regulations/SOR-2003-323/FullText.html) is

> [The person] (f) subject to subsection (2), has resided only in one or more of the following countries during the three-year period before the day on which the application was received and until the day on which the authorization is issued: (i) Canada or the United States, [...]